# Problems installing vim latex-suite

Tags: editors, vim

I'm working on mac.

- I donwloaded the archive 1.8.23 from the SourceForge page
- I extracted its contained files in my `~/.vim/` directory
- I made the necessary changes (described in de vim latex manual) in my `~/.vimrc` file (which I had to create because it did not exist yet)
- I opened vim and typed `:helptags ~/.vim/doc`
- I reopened vim and started editing an existing `.tex` file, but it seems vim latex-suite is not being loaded properly...

What am I doing wrong?
I tried several things, including going into the `~/.vim/` directory, and used `make`, but I got the following errors :

```
rm -rf -- ./vim-latex-1.8.23-20100914-r
svn export -r HEAD . vim-latex-1.8.23-20100914-r
svn: '.' is not a working copy
make: *** [snapshot] Error 1
```

EDIT : My `.vimrc` file [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/467509/vimrc).

Comment: I think we need more information.  What exactly is in your .vimrc?  What is the content of the .tex file you are trying to edit?

Comment: What does `:set ft?` say on the LaTeX file. Vim uses some heuristics to determine if the file is a tex, latex, or context file, and if the file is short then vim may misidentify it as a plain tex file. `:set ft?` should say `tex` (and not `plain_tex` or `context`)

Comment: @Aditya : it says `tex`, which is understandable (see my attached `.vimrc` file) --- @Jal Hlavacek : In a few seconds, I'm attaching my `.vimrc` file, which is very simple the fact being it has been created for the purpose to use vim latex-suite.

Comment: @Jan Hlavacek : The content of my `.tex` file is a usual file which we can compile using several conventional editors such as texshop on my mac and other windows based ones for my colleagues.

Comment: @Nigu I created a git repository containing vim configuration for simplifying plugin management, and made it public in case someone else finds it useful: https://bitbucket.org/drozdyuk/vimfiles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have tried `make` and not `make install`.

The Makefile is written such that `make` downloads the newest snapshot with SVN, and `make install` installs it. Try `make install` instead!

I would have written suggestion as a comment, but I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I had to do it in `sudo` mode to avoid all the permission clashes.

Comment: That's interesting!  The installation instructions on the vim-latex's website do not mention running `make` at all. I don't remember if I used `make` when installing vim-latex manually, since the last time I did that was before Debian started packaging it, which was quite a while ago.  Also, since you got permission clashes when running `make install` as a regular user, it seems that you actually installed vim-latex globally, rather than in your own .vim directory.  I still think that just unpacking into ~/.vim should be sufficient, I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: @Jan: You are right, the `make install` installs globally (to `$(DESTDIR)` which is set to `/usr/local/` on most systems). I also do not understand why unpacking into `~/.vim/` does not work. @Nigu: Can you post the output of `:set runtimepath?` ? It might help in debugging the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try `vim-addons install latex-suite` in a shell.